# Indicator for a spa

Tags: javascript, ajax, single-page-application

I'm trying to create a indicator for a single page website (website works with ajax) to display what percentage of the page is loaded (just like the one used in youtube).

Currently I'm just predicting the request time statistically, simply calculating the average time of all previous requests. Then I just show the animation for that time period.

Is there a right way to do this?

I just want to know a high level idea..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should definitely search before asking, as this kind of topic is bound to have many relevant posts that would most likely point you in the right direction.

Comment: what do you mean by "percentage of the page is loaded" ?

Comment: @john In youtube there is a thin bar at the top of every page to show loading. That bar starts filling, keep filling and finally disappears when page is fully loaded... I meant something like that..

Comment: most websites are faking this, maybe this is what youre looking for http://www.inwebson.com/demo/jpreloader/